# Visual Studio 2022 MS Build Toolversion and its Framework

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2022

What is current Toolversion for MS Build ToolVerions for VS2022 and what would be Framework version for .NetFramework. what is the version i can see in CsProj in project

Visual Studio 2022 ToolVersion in Csproj for .NetFrameWork

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Yes i got your answer and it was helpful too thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2022 and .Net Framework projects use `ToolsVersion="Current"` or `ToolsVersion="17.0"`. (The version of MSBuild that comes with VS2022 is 17.0.)

See more detail at [MSBuild Toolset (ToolsVersion)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-toolset-toolsversion?view=vs-2022).

When a new project is created Visual Studio uses a template. From the comments it appears that the template has not been updated since VS2017 and has `ToolsVersion="15.0"`. MSBuild 15 was provided with VS2017. You can simply edit the project file and update the `ToolsVersion`. If you only have VS2022 or MSBuild v17 installed, that version of MSBuild will be used even when the `ToolsVersion` is set to 15.

Comment: But when i Create console in .Net frame work with 4.8 and 4.8.1 framework, still i can see csproj file ToolVersion as "15.0", please tell me the steps were i can get version of 17 in .NetFramewoek

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{7DD7A021-42B1-4951-9C71-7961F39E2409}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>

Comment: The project template is still using 15. And you can leave it as that or edit the .csproj file to change the ToolsVersion. The actual version of MSBuild that comes with VS2022 is 17.0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Description of [ToolsVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/project-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022#attributes):

> The version of the Toolset MSBuild uses to determine the values for $(MSBuildBinPath) and $(MSBuildToolsPath).

MSBuild is installed in the \Current folder under each version of Visual Studio. You just need to change ToolsVersion="15.0" to ToolsVersion="Current" if you want to use MSBuild 17.0 in your project in Visual Studio 2022.

You can find the current folder from here `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current`
[image]

We can also see this from the detailed build output window:

> Project file contains ToolsVersion="15.0". This toolset may be unknown
> or missing, in which case you may be able to resolve this by
> installing the appropriate version of MSBuild, or the build may have
> been forced to a particular ToolsVersion for policy reasons. Treating
> the project as if it had ToolsVersion="Current". For more information,
> please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=293424.

The build may have been forced to ToolsVersion="Current" because the toolset for 15.0 could not be found. So it is not necessary to modify ToolsVersion.

Comment: yes this is clear for and it is working as expected